# How can i change rewrite rules without .htaccess file?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

**I have problem:**

I developped a website, and when i host it, i find that the server don't accept to create or to update the .htaccess file (security). the costumer don't want to change server and the server administrator don't have a solution.  can you help me?

Comment: Do you have ftp access?

Comment: yes i have, but i dont have a permission to create or to update .htaccess file .

Comment: Thats insane. I'd go with te second option of @AaronMiller 's answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to solve this problem is either to use a permalink scheme which requires no `.htaccess` changes, or to find a better web host.

Wordpress's permalink scheme relies on rewrite rules, and as far as I know there is no pure-PHP permalink implementation (and, absent major architecture changes, no such implementation can exist). Therefore, if you cannot modify the `.htaccess` file in your Wordpress instance's root directory, and (as I assume) you also cannot modify the Apache configuration file which applies to your site, then your two simplest options are either to give up on using any permalink scheme which requires changes to `.htaccess`, or to give up on your current web host entirely and find one which better supports your requirements.